# What do "count", "mean", and "sum" in QgsZonalStatistics mean?

Tags: qgis, python, statistics, zonal-statistics

I am working with `Qgis` and making some analytics of lightdata. 
I've used these commands:

```
rasterfile = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer().source()
vectorlayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
import qgis.analysis
zonalstats = qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics(vectorlayer,rasterfile)
zonalstats.calculateStatistics(None)
```

When I open the table I get `mean`, `count`, `sum`. 
What does it mean in this term? `count` - what is it counting? `sum` - what is it summarizing? `mean` - how does it calculate the mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on intuition I would say that the statistics probably represent the following. `count` is the number of pixels within the "zone", so for instance within the polygons you're aggregating to or something similar. `sum` is their combined total value. And `mean` the average for the zone/polygon: `sum`/`count`

Comment: So do you mean with pixels within the "zone" the "lightpoints" within a zone?

Comment: Yes, so the zonal statistics looks at the number of lightpoints which are represented by pixels with a value up to 63 I believe. So it counts the number of pixels within the zone, adds all the values together, and calculates the mean.

Comment: Good intuition (and correct). This kind of output in a raster table is standard across every GIS platform I've ever used. 9 times out of 10, however, it's completely useless information.

Comment: Does Qgis count only the bright points between dark and bright? Or does it count all the points which seem to be a little bit bright, then some which are brighter and so on? What do you mean with useless information? How can I do it better and accurate?

Comment: I guess this is the NOAA night light data you're working with, right? If so than QGIS counts the value of each pixel, which is between 0 and 63 (if I remember correctly), and adds them up.

Comment: The dataname is: F162004.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis
Do you mean with [0,63] that 0 is least brightness (not dark) and 63 is the most brightness?

Comment: Yes, so maybe for some more background information on the use of night light data you can consult the paper by Henderson et al. (2012), AER, "Measuring Economic Growth from Outer Space".

Comment: Wes. Can you tell me what you mean with useless information?

Comment: Guys? I would be glad, because it's very important.

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: I need to know what Wes meant with "This kind of output in a raster table is standard across every GIS platform I've ever used. 9 times out of 10, however, it's completely useless information." Does it mean, that I am doing it wrong? Is it a useless operation I did?

Comment: I can't speak for Wes of course but what I think he means to say is that in 90% of the cases the information from these kind of tables isn't really relevant. If this is also true in your case depends of course on what kind of analysis you want to do.

Comment: All I want is to analyze the intensity of light in a region. That's it. Are these tables enough?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of the data?

Comment: Yes I have. I recognized that dark areas have a lower mean than brighter areas. So I thought that I am on the right way. Or how do you see it?

Comment: For measuring light intensity I think that's a good start.